How to use a check valve for kitchen sink drain?
Here is the plumbing under my kitchen sink. This normally works just fine except sometimes  I have backwater coming up the kitchen sink. I was thinking to install a check valve to prevent this.
My question are:

Is that a good idea?
How and where to install it?



it is not clear what the problem is

sometimes the drainpipe underneath the kitchen  floor get clogged. these causes wastewater from the washing machine that is connected to the same pipe to go up the kitchen sink. i want to make the direction of the water only from the kitchen to the pipe

you are missing a vent pipe

@diy75 there is a vent pipe inside the wall

The water will need to go somewhere.  If not the kitchen sink, then maybe a smaller sink and get water all over the floor.  Maybe find out why the drain is clogging so often.

@DIY75 we can't tell whether or not the vent pipe is missing.  The P-trap stubs into the wall; we can only assume that there's a vent pipe in the wall.

OP, one other thing you're missing is a high loop on your dishwasher drain hose...

Check valves should not be used in residential plumbing drains.
You said you have a proper vent in the wall, so if water is backing up, you have a problem...a clog.
You can try to disconnect the drain going into the wall and snaking that. If that does not produce results you will need to hire a professional drain cleaning service or a plumber.
You should not "mask" the problem by installing a valve.
